# Silverlight 4 Services

Tags: silverlight, service, virtual-machine

I'm running Windows Server 2008 on a virtual box with an IIS webserver hosting my silverlight application. When I try to browse the app from the server (VM) on localhost:80, everything works fine and the services are found. But when I try to browse the app from another computer on the network, I can see the main screen and silverlight loads everything but when it goes to call a service, I get an exception:

SCRIPT5022: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.   at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
   at alisaWebApp.SecurityService.EncryptCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
   at alisaWebApp.LoginPage.securityClient_EncryptCompleted(Object sender, EncryptCompletedEventArgs e)
   at alisaWebApp.SecurityService.SecurityServiceClient.OnEncryptCompleted(Object state)

Not too sure what that can mean but my guess is that the service can't be found? But shouldn't the service be called from the web server and when I run the app from the server everything works. Maybe I'm missing something with port forwarding? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the inner exception for details?

The Silverlight application is running on the client machine, if you are using service references to localhost in the app config for the Silverlight application you will end up looking for services running on the client machine as well. This works when you are running the app on the web server, because the web server is also the client.

Comment: Oedipus, that worked but now when I try to access the site from the server it doesn't work :D. Is there any way to "detect" which reference to use or something? I mean for the server it would have to be 'localhost' and for clients the IP of the server, correct?

Answer (score 2):

The service will be called from the Silverlight app running in the user's browser if you are calling the service in your Silverlight code.  You'll need to allow specific ip's or all ip's to access to the service over http or https using a clientaccesspolicy.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <access-policy>
        <cross-domain-access>
            <policy>
                <allow-from http-request-headers= "SOAPAction">
                    <domain uri="http://*"/>
                </allow-from>
                <grant-to>
                    <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
               </grant-to>
           </policy>
        </cross-domain-access>
    </access-policy>
```

This file needs to be in the root directory of the web app.

You'll probably want to setup some security as well, unless you want the whole world to be able to use your service.

The other issue could be the ClientConfig file.  You'll need to change the service endpoint address in there if it is currently set to localhost (to your server ip).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting a cross domain exception.  Security associated with service access is not enforced when the SilverLight application is hosted at localhost.

If this is correct, check out this article on [cross domain access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).